# Is immediate powerdown bad for Ubuntu

Tags: shutdown, ext4, data-corruption, overclocking

I just got 17.04 because it runs Linux 4.10 which is optimized for my AMD Ryzen which I am overclocking and benchmarking. I am experimenting with extreme numbers, and quite often the computer freezes or powers off. Is this damaging to the operating system or the filesystem? Will I get errors after doing this 10-20 more times?

I am running Ubuntu on a Samsung 960 Evo NVMe SSD

Comment: Unlikely if the file system isn't being accessed (written)  the moment the freeze happens. Otherwise yes, very likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kind of unscheduled shutdown can result in file system damage, but a hard freeze *may be* less prone to it.

The problem arises if the shutdown occurs during an actual write to storage (HDD, SSD), or while files are open (changes to the contents may or may not have been written to storage, but updates to file size and location have not).  If this happens, you'll have at least one damaged file, which your OS may or may not be able to repair during the next startup (if you're not, you should run either redundant storage or at least a journaling filesystem like ext4).  If the damaged file is one your OS expects to open during startup, it may thrown an error or even cause startup to halt.

You can minimize issues, as noted above, by using a journaling filesystem or redundant storage (a suitable RAID level).  Neither of these is bulletproof, but both give an improved chance for the OS to recover during the next startup.

Even more important, don't keep *anything* important solely stored on this experimental system -- or, put another way, don't experiment on your production system.  The machine you use to store your family pictures is not a good choice to experiment with overclocking, oddball file systems, bleeding edge kernels, or anything else that might be less than fully stable.  Keep your important information on a system running within published hardware specs, and on an LTS OS version (currently 14.04 or 16.04).

Comment: is there an effective way to check for errors besides dmesg? i am running ext4

Comment: You can use `fsck` from command line, and `gparted` can do it from the GUI -- these only work on an unmounted volume, however, so for your system volume (/) you'd have to boot from a Live media or another Linux OS partition to check that partition.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this damaging to the operating system or the filesystem?

No. A freeze means the file system isn't touched anymore. In case something does get damaged the power down is not the cause.

It is the overclocking that would be the cause. All the other issues are an *effect* from that.

Comment: Depends on the age of your computer - nice discussion here - https://www.howtogeek.com/181295/yes-its-okay-to-shut-down-your-computer-with-the-power-button/

Comment: Are you sure that applied to Unix/Linux? I seem to remember the system did a "sync" "sync" back then before powering down.

Comment: I recall old computers that will immediately shut down when you press the power button. The OS does not have time to do anything. Such a configuration is not the case these days.